Where is the state kept for the items under the "Configuration Checklist" page?
I was clicking on the items in the "Configuration Checklist" screen and noticed they changed from "RED" to "GREEN".
I wish to put these items back to their "RED" state to remind other users to review them.
I assume the state is either kept in the DB or a cache file. If DB, please let me know which table. If cache file, please let me know its location.

oh 'state' as in 'status', not State as in State/Province. hmm. good question. not spotting a relevant table in the db.

Yes, 'state' as in 'status'. I want to return these items back to their original (not yet viewed) state.

Short Answer:
Sit back and drink some coffee or a comforting beverage of your choice. They will magically work as long as they are using a different computer/web browser profile to you.
Medium Answer:
The bad news is you can't really reset these without clearing your browser history for the pages in question.
The good news is that unless you share a browser with the people that you wish to remind to reset these you don't need to do anything! Unless they have already visited those pages.
Long answer:
If you inspect the element you will see that it's getting the colour styles from the ':visited' selector. This pseudo-class is applied by the browser to pages that you have visited.
Non-recommended answer:
If you really really wanted - you can change the link by adding an additional URL param so the browser will not treat it as visited.
You'll need to edit:
templates/CRM/Admin/Page/ConfigTaskList.tpl
and change all the links (find them by searching for destination) add a url parameter after the '}' and before the '"' and include the ampersand as a separator.
Note if you upgrade CiviCRM these changes will be lost - but hopefully by this stage everything is configured anyway...
This will be found in different places depending on your CMS - Drupal 10 would be vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/ (but in Joomla, Drupal 7/Backdrop, and Wordpress it will be where the code for civicrm lives i.e. modules or plugins )

Ahhh - the information is kept on the client machine, thanks Luke. I tried this on another machine and verified all the items in the "Configuration Checklist" are RED.
